# Scala Play Slick RejectedExecutionException on ScalaTest runs

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, slick, scalatest

My FlatSpec tests are throwing:

```
 java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@dda460e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4f489ebd[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
```

**But only when I run more than one suite**, on the second suite forward; it seems there's something that isn't reset between tests. I'm using `OneAppPerSuite` to provide the app context. Whenever I use `OneAppPerTest`, it fails again after the first test/Suite.

I have a `override def beforeEach = tables.foreach ( _.truncate )` set up to clear the tables, where `truncate` just deletes all from a table: `Await.result (db.run (q.delete), Timeout.Inf)`

I have the following setup for my DAO layer:

```
SomeMappedDaoClass extends SomeCrudBase with HasDatabaseConfig
```

where

```
trait SomeCrudBase { self: HasDatabaseConfig => 
  override lazy val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
  implicit lazy val context = Akka.system.dispatchers.lookup("db-context")
}
```

And in `application.conf`

```
db-context {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 5
    parallelism-max = 100
  }
}
```

I was refactoring the code to move away from Play's Guice DI. Before, when it had `@Inject() (val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)` and extended `HasDatabaseConfigProvider` instead on the DAO classes, everything worked perfectly. Now it doesn't, and I don't know why.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just out of interest is `SomeMappedDaoClass` an `object`? (I know it says class but...).

When testing the Play framework I have run into this kind of issue when dealing with `object`s that setup connections to parts of the Play Framework.

Between tests and between test files the Play `app` is killed and restarted, however, the `object`s created persist (because they are `object`s, they are initialised once within a JVM context--I think).

This can result in an `object` with a connection (be it for slick, an actor, anything...) that is referencing the first instance of the `app` used in a test. When the `app` is terminated and a new test starts a new `app`, that connection is now pointing to nothing.

Comment: I managed to stitch together a workaround by re-fetching `dbConfig` for every operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48298160/1090166

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and in my case, the above answers did not work out.
My Solution -

```
implicit val app = new FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())
Play.start(app)
```

Add above code in your first test case and don't add Play.stop(app). As all the test cases are already refering the first application, it should not be terminated. This worked for me.